# package require XXXX tcl

Tags: software-installation

I have to install a program but it always fails. 
When I try package require XXX, it return "can't find package XXX". 
I have a folder with the setup files in it, among which there is a pkgIndex.tcl,
I have been looking online about package and pkgIndex.tcl but I cannot find any clear explanation. All this is a bit confusing for me...

Comment: What is the package name?

Answer (score 1):

The folder with the pkgIndex file, is that directory in the `auto_path`?

```
lappend auto_path /my/folder
package require xyz
```

See the [tutorial chapter on packages](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl31.html) and the wiki page http://wiki.tcl.tk/auto_path